# How to capture a subset within a set using regex

Tags: regex

Test string: www.test.com/abcd_20180508_efgh

The goal is to capture 20180508 and then check the first 4 digits (in this case, 2018) for a date parser.

I can capture the digits using \d{8}, but from there I don't know how to capture the 2018 portion.

Is there a way to do this? I need to extract the first 4 digits because 20**2005**08 would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(?<![^\W_])(\d{4})\d{4}(?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryvaYS/1).

**Details**

- `(?<![^\W_])` - a word boundary excluding the position between an underscore (equal to `(?<=\b|_)`)
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1: four digits
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?![^\W_])`  - a word boundary excluding the position between an underscore (equal to `(?=\b|_)`)